# Flex nested item overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I want to have the part under "foo" totally scrollable, yet I haven't been able to achieve it using flexbox. I've tried it with `min-height`, but without any success.

https://jsfiddle.net/szd5tvfc/2/

```js
  $('.ui.dropdown')
    .dropdown();
```

```css
.ui.vertical.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item,
.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item>.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui vertical menu">
    <div class="item">
      <h3 class="ui header">Select foos</h3>
      <div class="ui icon search input">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search foo..." />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Selected foos
      <div class="scrolling menu">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo name</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="overflowing item">
      foos
      <div class="scrolling menu">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">Foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: max-height: 100vh; to .ui.vertical.menu and flex:1 to  overflowing item

Comment: Please add your code the the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the `overflow` property to work, there needs to be a defined height somewhere along the line. Otherwise, how does the property know where to overflow? It will just keep extending the box.

Try this.

```
.ul.vertical.menu { height: 100vh; }

.overflowing.item { flex-basis: 1px; flex-grow: 1; }
```

```css
.ui.vertical.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;  
}

.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item {
  flex-basis: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1; 
}

.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item,
.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item>.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
  <div class="ui vertical menu">
    <div class="item">
      <h3 class="ui header">Select foos</h3>
      <div class="ui icon search input">
        <i class="search icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search foo..." />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      Selected foos
      <div class="scrolling menu">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo name</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="overflowing item">
      foos
      <div class="scrolling menu">
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">Foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div class="content">foo</div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vt5x0dhc/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS to your code:

```
.ui.vertical.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item,
.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item>.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

It uses `justifycontent: strech;` and the `flex-shrink`/`flex-grow` properties.

Here is the link to a fully functional fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamtheanonymouskoder/spd3z2wa/8/).

**Note that the flex parent's height can be adjusted freely and it won't cause any sort of extra scrollbars or anything.**

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure if I understood what you want but to get scroll you need to set `max-height` instead `min-height`.

```
   .ui.vertical.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item,
.ui.vertical.menu>.overflowing.item>.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Check the changes below

https://jsfiddle.net/r4bxu5ep/

Comment: Hey! Thanks for taking the time to help, but unfortunately this solves my problem only partially. Of course setting an arbitrary height works, still, what I'd want to do is to have a solution that adjusts as the content changes.

Comment: if you set the height to auto and then set a max-height property will adjust the content and then when reach the max value will give you a scroll

like this
https://jsfiddle.net/v9hn3z4e/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29433987)

Comment: @Dragonthoughts thank you for your comment, this was my first answer here. I edited my answer (: